# Revert to Support Library from Android Jetpack

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-jetpack

We have a library created with the new Android Jetpack support libraries, but the project we need to import the library is designed with Android Support Library and it has migration issues, so migrating that project to AndroidX is not the solution. Rather, we're seeking for how to revert back the library itself to the original support library from Android Jetpack components.

I was able to get a build with **jetifier-standalone** but, it needs to be uploaded to a remote maven storage, and needed to be fetched from the target project there, and the generated pom.xml file is wrong. The only solution I'm seeking for is to revert back all Android Jetpack libraries to Android Support libraries. How can I do that without manually changing every dependency, package, views etc...?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: revert to the previous sdk and gradle you were using, however you will not be able to use new features anymore.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not entirely sure how reverting gradle version will change anything. Could you elaborate on that? Right now it just gives an error that the old gradle version is not supported.